# MVC3 : how to incorporate @Html.DisplayFor in a iframe src?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

I tried figuring it out as well as google for answer, but it still does not work.

Basically in my Details.cshtml, this code: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.eLink) is generating a URL link out (eg. http://www.w3schools.com) out from the database based on the id no.

However, I need this URL link to come out in a iframe. How do I incorporate this code:

**@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.eLink)**

to here?

Comment: <iframe src="http://www.w3school.com" width="1000" height="300" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: so when you call `DisplayFor`, you want it to generate an `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Html.DisplayFor is to display the value of a property of your view as text. It is not its job to put it in an iframe. it is not what you need to use.

You wrote the html that you seek. So just use your model.eLink in the iframe:

```html
<iframe src="@Model.eLink"; width="1000" height="300" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```